# Recaptcha missing the element "data-sitekey" making it impossible to use any captcha service apis

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, recaptcha

As the above title says, I'm attempting to use a captcha solving service but all of them request a code that's attached to an element called "data-sitekey" that should be in the HTML of a page with recaptcha on it. My problem is that the webpage I'm looking at doesn't have a "data-sitekey" element, meaning I can't use any of the apis. Any help in finding the elusive "data-sitekey" is much appreciated, or any recommendations for a service that doesn't require it. I'm coding in Python + Selenium, but I'm reasonably confident using Python to inject JavaScript into the page so any solutions focused around those two languages would be most helpful.

Here is the website I'm looking at : https://mailchi.mp/box/xbox-series-x-restock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this one: `6Lexz1YUAAAAAJZknL3EkeY_xBlIKGKGfGwFHhjK`

There's invisible captcha so it performs request to google api for response.

Sitekey is in API request

https:/ /www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=strong text**6Lexz1YUAAAAAJZknL3EkeY_xBlIKGKGfGwFHhjK**&co=restofthelink

Comment: Thank you! I'm now able to query the API of the captcha service I use. Now I just need to figure out why the token returned doesn't work, but that's a separate problem! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DoesntEven did you manage to get it to work? I have troubles with the same problem as the website response tells me my captcha token is invalid. Is there a way to make a valid (working) request to some website protected with recaptchav3, while getting captcha response from a third party captcha-solve service? I'm stuck with it

Comment: I think it was buried in an iframe or something. I can't actually remember the exact solution.